# Response listener to listen to both String and Bitmap

Tags: java, android

How do I listen to both String and Bitmap? I need to volley the image and the name of it into my database

```
final String name = etItemname.getText().toString();
            Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable)ivImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            Response.Listener<String> StringListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                   //not implemented ( if else statement )
                }
            };
            UploadRequest uploadRequest = new UploadRequest(image, name, StringListener );
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Home.this)
            queue.add(uploadRequest);
```

Comment: Your question does not make sense. One cannot listen to a string. Or to a bitmap.  Please log  `response`. What do you get?

Comment: i'm encoding the image into base64 format already so i'll just listen to string

Comment: Your comment does not make sense. One cannot listen to a string. Why did you not tell which `response` you get?

Comment: i just started doing androids so i'm nt really sure

Comment: i think you want to upload Base64String of image using volley right?

Comment: yes i'm trying to get the image name uploaded too but i changed my mind and i'd fetch the image name to incremental decimal that is fetched from database instead of inserting image name.. so now i nid to upload the image to the database now